# My domain-name Regex needs refining

Tags: regex

I am using this regex  to detect if the user has included the protocol when entering a domain name - which i don't want them to do:

```
if (/^[^http:\/\/|www.][a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(co\.uk|com|net|biz|org|org\.uk|eu|me\.uk)$/i.test(inp2){
  ... ok ...
}
```

It's working 97% of the time then i realised why some names were failing - its not matching the entire
protocol its matching anything that has the characters h,t,t,p or w,w,w instead of treating them as whole words 'http//:'  or  'www.'

i found out when testing with:

```
**hattooflat.com**
```

which SHOULD pass but the chars h,t,t are making it fail

I think i need word boundaries \b but im not sure where:

```
(/^\b[^http:\/\/|www.]\b[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.( .....
```

or

```
(/^[^\bhttp:\b\/\/|\bwww\b.][a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.( .....
```

I know im close - regexes are still giving me grief after 4 years dev'ing

Comment: What regex engine are you using? If the engine can support negative lookaheads, that's what you'd be able to use.

Comment: Instead of entering a shitload of arbitrary TLD's you might just want to use `([A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.)?[a-z]{2,6}` at the end.

Comment: You cannot use square brackets to group substrings.

Comment: sorry, not sure what you mean  - but im using jquery 1.8.3/Javascript  @ Niels Keurentjes i usually do use your idea but in this application its important that only those tlds stated are allowed @speakr can you give me an idea of what i need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you need **[look-aheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**:

```
/^(?!https?:\/\/|www\.)[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(co\.uk|com|net|biz|org|org\.uk|eu|me\.uk)$/i
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/9gZMN/)**.

---

Short explanation:

- `^`: Match the beginning of the string (supposing a one-line input).
- `(?!<...>)`: Do **not** consume any characters, but look ahead and make sure that the next part of the string does **not** match `<...>` (negative look-ahead).
- `https?:\/\/|www\.`: Match either `http://` or `https://` or `www.` (`?` after 's' makes it "optional").
- `[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+`: Match any sequence containing one or more alphanumeric characters or '-'.
- `\.`: Match one dot ('.').
- `(co\.uk|com|net|biz|org|org\.uk|eu|me\.uk)`: Match either `co.uk` or `com` or `net` or ...
- `$`: Match the end of the string (supposing a one-line input).

Comment: Ok the guy who gave the first answer keeps deleting his post so cant mark it - as yours also has a good fiddle example and explanation which importantly will help me to learn in future i marked yours  - many thanks

Comment: @user962902 There is a big difference between this answer and Puuskis. See Ian Roberts answer, it explains it.

Comment: i know that now - that's why it was deleted cos it was wrong -though produced the right result - however i wasnt able to communicate that to Puuskis

Answer (score 2):

Square brackets in a regular expression denote a character class, so

```
[^http:\/\/|www.]
```

means the same as `[^:/|.htpw]` and matches any *single character* that is not h, t, p, :, /, |, w or .  You probably want a negative lookahead instead

```
^(?!https?:\/\/|www\.)
```

which matches a string that does not start with `http://`, `https://` or `www.`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to identify domain names without protocol and subdomains, why not use this regex:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-])+[a-z0-9])\.(co\.uk|com|net|biz|org|org\.uk|eu|me\.uk)$
```

The regex allows domain names with length 2 and domain names with length 3 including non-consecutive (non-trailing, non-leading) hyphens.

Comment: it was important that ONLY the tlds stated were allowed and no others - also ^[a-z0-9\-] ALLOWS http, www they're just chars like the domain name

Comment: @user962902 Okay, I fixed that.